# Does Hashmap autosort?

Tags: java, date, hashmap

This is my hashmap :

```
HashMap<Long, Day> hashMapTest = new HashMap<Long, Day>();
```

and I insert `Date.getTime()` into this hashmap like :

```
Date start = new Date(vonDatum.getTime());

for (int i = 0; i < tagediff; i++)
  {
    Day day= new Day(start);
    this.mitarbeiterTagHashMap.put(start.getTime(), day);
    CalendarUtil.addDaysToDate(start, 1);
  }
```

The strange thing is when I call the hashmap with, the order is completely an other and the keys doesnt fit to the insertion :

```
for (Long name : hashMapTest.keySet())
 {
     Window.alert(name + ": " + hashMapTest.get(name));
 }
```

Comment: What do you need - keeping the order of insertion(LinkedHashMap<K,V>) or sorting by keys (Interface SortedMap<K,V>)? These are different requirements.

Comment: `HashMap` does not do any sort, also it does not maintain the insertion order.

Comment: *"The strange thing is ..."*  The **really** strange thing is that you didn't bother to check the javadocs for `HashMap` :-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> The strange thing is when i call the hashmap with, the order is
>   completly an other and the keys doesnt fit to the insertion :

[HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) does NOT maintain the order of insertion but there is an alternative called [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) that maintains the insertion order. Or if you want the keys to be sorted in natural order(using keys compareTo method) then you may go for [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

Answer (score 9):

Following are 4 common implementation of Map interface in Java,

**HashMap**: No ordering & No preservation of insertion order on keys/values

**LinkedHashMap**: Preserves the insertion order

**TreeMap**: Ordered by the key

**HashTable**: Unlike HashMap, it is synchronized

Refer [here](http://www.programcreek.com/2013/03/hashmap-vs-treemap-vs-hashtable-vs-linkedhashmap/) for better understanding with examples.

Answer (score 5):

No, `HashMap`s don't sort their keys automatically.

You want a `TreeMap` for sorting the keys, or a `LinkedHashMap` to retain the insertion order.

Here's an example:

```
long l0 = 0l;
long l1 = 1l;
Map<Long, String> hashMap = new HashMap<Long, String>();
Map<Long, String> treeMap = new TreeMap<Long, String>();
Map<Long, String> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<Long, String>();
// does not guarantee key order 1, 0
hashMap.put(l1, null);
hashMap.put(l0, null);
// guarantees key order 0, 1
treeMap.put(l1,  null);
treeMap.put(l0,  null);
// guarantees key order 1, 0
linkedHashMap.put(l1,  null);
linkedHashMap.put(l0,  null);
System.out.printf("HashMap: %s%nTreeMap: %s%nLinkedHashMap: %s%n", hashMap, treeMap, linkedHashMap);
```

**Output**

```
HashMap: {0=null, 1=null}
TreeMap: {0=null, 1=null}
LinkedHashMap: {1=null, 0=null}
```