# Get first k values from HashMap

Tags: java, string, hashmap

I am trying to get first k values from a hashmap.

I know how to get all values from a hashmap and also how to iterate over all of them. Is there any short way to generate first k values from hashmap

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> en : hmap.entrySet()) 
{ 
        System.out.println("Key = " + en.getKey() + ", Value = " + en.getValue());
}
```

Comment: "HashMap does NOT maintain the order of insertion but there is an alternative called LinkedHashMap that maintains the insertion order. Or if you want the keys to be sorted in natural order(using keys compareTo method) then you may go for TreeMap." (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296911/does-hashmap-autosort)

Comment: There is no concept of "first" in a hash map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The notion of the first elements is undefined for `Map` interface. How it was mentioned in comments you can use `LinkedHashMap` or `TreeMap` where the *first* item make sense.

If you just want to get some limit number of map values, you could use stream api with [`limit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit-long-):

```
hmap.entrySet().stream()
    .limit(2)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```